# Pymongo Create Role Issue

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I am using the below code to create a new role.

```js
db.createRole(
    {
        createRole: "role-name",
        privileges: [
            {resource: {db: "weather_db", collection: ""},
             actions: ["insert", "update", "find", "delete"]}
        ],
        roles: [{role: "read", db: "db1"}]
    })
```

However I keep getting the following error:

```
NameError : name "CREATEROLE" not defined
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

pymongo can be confusing because in many respects the command syntax is similar or sometimes exactly the same as the commands in the mongo shell.

However pymongo and shell commands are not the same. If you want to use the pymongo version, you need to check the [pymongo documentation](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/index.html), and this is especially true of administrative tasks.

Also, pymongo's key-value pairs are represented as python `dict`s. So any keys must be quoted, i.e.

```
{"key": "value"}
```

and not

```
{key: "value"}
```

From the documentation there is no specific task to create a role, but from the [MongoDB documentation for db.createRole](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createRole/) it states:

> The db.createRole() method wraps the [createRole](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/createRole/#dbcmd.createRole) command.

And pymongo does allow you to run commands using  the [`db.command()` method](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/database.html?highlight=db.command#pymongo.database.Database.command).

Finally, `delete` is not a built-in action; you want `remove`.

Putting it all together looks like:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

db = MongoClient()['admin']

db.command("createRole", "role-name",
           privileges=[{"resource": {"db": "weather_db", "collection": ""}, 
                        "actions": ["insert", "update", "find", "remove"]}],
           roles=[])
```